# simple xml not working on live server

Tags: php, simplexml, zoho

I have script which calls zoho api, Its working fine on localhost but when i upload the script to server it doesnt works, errror says

```
Severity: Warning
Message: simplexml_load_file(https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/xml/Leads/getMyRecords?newFormat=1&apikey={removed}&ticket={removed}): failed to open stream: Connection refused
Filename: models/xml_model.php
Line Number: 25
```

I checked php.ini settings to check if simple xml is enables, i can see its enabled. I also can see "allow_url_fopen" for both local and master is set to "ON"

Is there anything i must check ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look to the output of:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

What does it show in "Registered PHP Streams"? Do you see "https" on that line?

If not, just add:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

to your php.ini file and restart the web server. It will load OpenSSL extension.

Comment: I just saw phpinfo() and i can see https is there. "https, ftps, compress.zlib, compress.bzip2, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, phar, zip", these are the values listed for "Registered PHP streams"